# How to dynamically set HTML form action url in Jinja2?

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am trying to implement an admin page in flask using jinja2, where a list of users is displayed in a tabular form. The columns are UserID, Username and a Delete button column which just has delete buttons for each user. The table is as follows:

```
   <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Username</th>
            <th scope="col">Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            {% for i in users.items %}
            {% set temp= i.id %}

            <tr>
                <th id="this_id" scope="row">{{i.id}}</th>
                <td>{{ i.username }}</td>
                <td><button type="button" id="delete-button" onclick="button_listen(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal2">Delete</button></td>
            </tr> 

            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Upon clicking the delete button a modal opens which confirms the delete action

```
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Are you sure you want to delete?</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      <form id="modal_form" method="POST">
          <input class="btn btn-danger" action="{{url_for('users.delete_user', user_id=2)}}" type="submit" value="Delete">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the input form, the action attribute has the url redirect to a route. I want to set this action attribute dynamically upon a delete button click. I have tried using javascript to construct the action attribute string upon click of the delete button:

```
function button_listen(button_id) {
      const u_id=button_id.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].data;
      const comm1="{% raw %} {{url_for('users.delete_user', user_id={%endraw%}"
      const comm2=")}}"
      const fin=comm1+u_id+comm2
      document.getElementById("modal_form").setAttribute("action", fin)}
```

But that didn't cause Jinja2 to recognize the string as python code and rather routed me to an address as such:

```
http://localhost/{{url_for('users.delete_user',user_id=2)}}
```

How can I get this to work so that the route is properly interpreted ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that concatenate in JS before Jinja2 rendering will not be run by Jinja2 which runs before the JS. So the following will not work as intended (as you noticed):

```
  const u_id=button_id.parentElement.parentElement.childNodes[1].childNodes[0].data;
  const comm1="{% raw %} {{url_for('users.delete_user', user_id={%endraw%}"
  const comm2=")}}"
  const fin=comm1+u_id+comm2
```

The above code will not be rendered by Jinja2 because it will not be recognized as Jinja2 statements. The Jinja2 executes before JavaScript. A way to achieve what you want could be to try to render the `form_url` by Jinja2 into `{{ form_url }}`, check that it actually renders into an URL and then manipulate that URL with JavaScript so that it also takes the `u_id` parameter, maybe as a path parameter.

For example, create the `form_url` with Python/Jinja2 so that it becomes something like `/action/delete/` and then use JavaScript to put on a path parameter to the URL so that the URL becomes `/action/delete/42` for a specific user id.

I did not actually try this but I expect it will work.